# Chrome Extension - Not saving data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't get my Chrome extension to save data correctly.

Here is my current code

```html
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
//Split URL by variables
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
  var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
    }
    return(false);
}


function saveTicket2(ticket, contents) {
//Save the data to local storage
 chrome.storage.local.set({ticket : contents}, function() {
 console.log('Saved', ticket, contents);
 });
}

function setData(ticketID, result) {
//If data exists. Set it.
 document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value = result[ticketID];
 document.getElementsByName('message')[1].value = result[ticketID];
 console.log(result);
}

//Grab Ticket ID 
var ticketID = getQueryVariable("id");

//Retrieve data if it exists
try  {
 chrome.storage.local.get(ticketID, function(result) {
 if (result) {
 setData(ticketID, result);
 }
 });
} catch(err) {
 console.log(err.message);
}


//Save ticket contents to local storage every 5 seconds
window.setInterval(function() {
 var contents= document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value;
 var contents= document.getElementsByName('message')[1].value;
 saveTicket2(ticketID, contents);
}, 5000);
```

Within saveTicket2 the log works fine

```
Saved 222222 text
```

The log within setData logs an empty object

So the chrome.storage.local.set seems to pass without error but it doesn't actually save anything.

From [Chrome Storage Developer Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) the example given is as follows

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
  // Notify that we saved.
  message('Settings saved');
});
```

Which is what I have. The storage permission is also in my manifest.

If I add the following to saveTicket2, right after the .set it also returns an empty object, confirming I'm either accessing it wrong or saving it wrong.

```html
 chrome.storage.local.get(ticket, function(result1) {
 console.log(result1);
 });
```

Does anyone know why this isn't saving?

Comment: BTW, code snippets don't make sense for chrome extensions because the snippet can't run in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ticket : contents}, function() {
console.log('Saved', ticket, contents);
});
```

**The value of ticket hasn't set successfully.**

It will work in this way:

```
function saveTicket2(ticket, contents) {
//Save the data to local storage
var dataObj = {};
dataObj[ticketID] = contents;
chrome.storage.local.set(dataObj, function(){
    if(!chrome.runtime.lastError){
        console.log('Saved', ticket, contents);
    }   
});
}
```

This is my test code:

```
function saveTicket2(ticket, contents) {
//Save the data to local storage
var dataObj = {};
dataObj[ticketID] = contents;
chrome.storage.local.set(dataObj, function(){
    if(!chrome.runtime.lastError){
        console.log('Saved', ticket, contents);
    }   
});}

function setData(ticketID, result) {
//If data exists. Set it.
console.log("setData: ", result);
}

//Grab Ticket ID    
var ticketID = "55555";

//Retrieve data if it exists
function getData(){
try{
    chrome.storage.local.get(ticketID, function(result) {
        if (result){
            console.log(result);            
            setData(ticketID, result[ticketID]);
        }
    });
}catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
}

//Save ticket contents to local storage every 5 seconds
window.setInterval(function() {
var contents= new Date().getTime();
saveTicket2(ticketID, contents);
}, 3000);
window.setInterval(function() {
getData();
}, 5000);
```

If you want to know more about usage of chrome.storage, pls go to [How to set a simple dynamic variable into chrome.storage.local.set for a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594080/how-to-set-a-simple-dynamic-variable-into-chrome-storage-local-set-for-a-chrome/32598658#32598658)

Comment: can some one tell me how to push the data into an array and save this array to be able to add the new values to this array ........................